# Codename one open a file from filesystemstorage

Tags: file, codenameone

How can I open a file that is saved with the `FileSystemStorage`?
The app should use the build in features of the OS. So if it is an image open the OS image viewer, if the file is a PDF open the OS's pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
Display.getInstance().execute(fullPathToFile);
```

Although it might not work on all platforms.